# Is there some way to force the user to indicate render engine in use?

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

Just wondering out loud if there is some method or process when a user submits a question to make an indication of render engine (BI, Cycles, Game Engine, or external) a mandatory data point?

It seems a lot time is wasted when users don't indicate what engine they're working with.

In a broader sense, what if there was a pre-question checklist of common questions that Answerers ask in comments when trying to understand the question?

Comment: Don't waste time trying to answer something without first asking in the comments what Render Engine the OP expects to use.  If it's not clear, don't jump in.

Comment: That's what I mean, we waste time having to ask what render engine every time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the site does not yet acknowledge the massive differences in Blender awareness between new users and people with 100+ reputation (to pick a reasonable value is hard). I also think you have a point if you're saying there should some kind of in-text-box message for the first few questions of an account, a checklist as you say.

---

> Weclome! We notice you haven't posted any questions on Blender.Stackexchange before. Help us help you by including the following information in your question, often we need to know a few simple facts before we give useful answers.
>
> - What rendering engine are you using? (show image of the dropdown)
> - What operating system? (show how to find)
> - What version of Blender (show how to find)
> - Add screenshots (show how to make, and crop)

---

wording can be debated, but the overall content covers it right?

> > Weclome! We notice you haven't posted any questions on Blender.Stackexchange before. Increase your chances of getting a useful answer by including the following information in your question, often we need to know a few simple facts before answering.

SE could do blind-tests and roll out different messages, to see which messages work best, -- things like this can be measured objectively.

---

And I don't think it would hurt to emphasize in an automated way for new posters the following (shorter wording would be nicer).

> If someone adds a comment below your Question feel free to edit your original question to include additional information. Avoid going into discussion in the comments, you can delete your own comments to keep that area less noisy for any additional questions.

Comment: While a message like that would help in a lot of cases, adding the OS blender version, and render engine would not make a big difference for questions like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34818/2217).

Comment: Blender bug reports also don't often really need half of the required fields to be solved, but they are asked anyway so in the event that it is important it doesn't need to be asked. Picking out that example where it is irrelevant misses the point. My utopian brain thinks about a self diagnostic test which guides a new user towards a nice question..

Comment: On the other hand I also don't want a new user to see that as too much effort, so it would have to be really short and incredibly well conceived, and offer a pathway like " It's OK, I know exactly what i'm asking " to let them jump straight in.

Answer (score 1):

While it is a good idea that could work rather well for our site, no it is currently not possible.
This was suggested on the meta a year ago: [Can meta-style 'required tags' be implemented on non-meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195184/278094)

Beyond required tags, there is definitely no way to force a user to add their render engine (or anything else) to the body or title of their question.

---

I'm not totaly convinced that requiring all questions to fit in to four categories is a good idea. What happens when a user asks about, modeling (second biggest tag), or python (biggest tag). Both of those tags can stand alone without any of your suggested four required tags.

While I sure agree that there is a lot of time wasted simply asking what render engine the OP is using, I think with a system like this there would be just as many cases where a question does not really fit one of the tags.

We would run the risk of:

- Having too many required tags to make it worth it.
- The tags become too general to be meaningful.
- Miscatgorized questions, because a tag is required.

Take this question as an example, you had to pick at least one of these: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [support](/questions/tagged/support) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
It is not a bug report, this is not really asking for support either. So you are left with feature request, and discussion. Now depending on whether or not you are asking the devs to implement this, would rule out feature request. Thus you are left with discussion, and cant we discuss anything.
That is my point, for the required tag system to work you have to have overly general tags.

It works on meta because only questions about the site come here, but in blender anything is possible and questions can be about anything.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't really thinking about enforced tags, which would have the issue you're describing. I was imagining something more along the lines of a pre-flight checklist to be shown to the user before submission of the question.